# How to check whether (X) button in clicked in popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the value to the hidden field in parent window from child window and want to set the value to the parent window only when popup window is closed.

This is working fine when i use button to close the window.

The script for the button is:
onclick="javascript:window.close();"

But the same condition fails when i click (X) button in title bar. Can anyone help me out with this issue

Comment: Do you have any return false tied to the onunload event handler ?

Comment: No I dont have any return for that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to do this is to use window.onunload but this event is also fired when you press ctrl+r (i.e. on refresh) so just check this out.

Comment: is there a way to block the refresh of a window to prevent that from being a potential issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use onBeforeUnload.

Comment: I am using struts tags in this jsp to dispaly error message.

<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
  <s:iterator value="actionErrors">
   <font color="red"><p id="message" class="errorMessage" ><s:property escape="false" /></p></font>
  </s:iterator>
 </s:if>

Comment: What happens is the page is reloaded again and this method i called twice.

Comment: This is same with onunload also

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmClose()
    {
       if ((event.clientY < 0) ||(event.altKey) ||(event.ctrlKey)||((event.clientY < 129) && (event.clientY>107)))
        {
//event.altKey When press Alt +F4
//event.ctrlKey When press Ctrl +F4
//event.clientY 107 or 129 is  Alt F4 postion on window screen it may change base on screen resolution
alert('window closing');
        }
    }
</script>

<body topmargin='0'  onbeforeunload="ConfirmClose()">
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) very easy to create popup's. This prevents the browser from blocking "real" popups, and the issues you described here.

Answer (score 0):

Document for you: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Shift+X",function() {
    alert("Hi there!");
});
```

Download: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js